# SQL Insert query, working all day but now fails everytime

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

What could cause the following error for the very first time when the exact same code (that produces this error) has been working *perfectly* all day today?

> ---
>
> --------------------------- A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> ### --------------------------- OK

The code:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            try
            {
                // Insert into database
                sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DBHost + ";Initial Catalog=BLAHBLAH;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DBUserName + ";Password=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DBPassword + ";");

                sqlconnection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

                int count = 0;

                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Images (Name, Games) values ('" + item.Value + "', '" + games + "')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }

            sqlconnection.Close();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: network error? Perhaps? have you debugged it to see it can open a connection? And can you open a connection manually?

Comment: or victim of an Sql Injection?

Comment: Make sure you started `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` service?

Comment: Create a **test.udl** file on the machine and check the SQL DB connection. Also please use parameterized queries :)

Comment: Are you able to open your Sql server manually? if you can then check your Sql Connection string. it may have problem on it.

Comment: I can open a connection and edit tables using Navicat. I can also (in my own Connection Settings Form in my app) successfully Open the connection to the db. It's just when I go to the other Form in my app where I try to do an INSERT it fails - but it's been working all day with no probs. I don't understand how it can just stop working (the exact same code is used in the conn settings form where it still works)

Comment: @HassanNisar, Thanks for test.udl, I didn't know about it, it's handy

Comment: And after you figured out why your connection / network / etc is lost & fixed it, please remove that cursor-stuff and bulk-insert all values from 'var item in files' in one go, with 1 query.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to thank everyone for their help and suggestions. I've managed to solve this problem.

As it turns out, the reason this code was failing was because there was an issue with retrieving setting data from Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName. The settings are there and saved, but it wasn't able to retrieve the settings into variables for some reason.

I got this code to work by storing settings somewhere else other than Properties.Settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is Sql server network connection error. try to login in sql browser also check your sql service is running or not and try to debug your code that are you able to open connection check/login credentials.